# Battery icon is fuzzy in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit Gnome

Tags: 16.04, indicator, battery

My battery icon is fuzzy in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit Gnome 3, but at the same time, if I click it, it can present battery life in percentages. So what would be the problem with it?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: image: http://fpaste.dy.fi/K32

Comment: I noticed that once the level drops to 59% a new image is used. Not nearly enough precision in the graphic here.