# Gnome - battery icon not accurate

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, indicator, battery

On Gnome Ubuntu 16.04, my battery icon is mostly useless. The visual gauge is always far behind the true level, which I display as percentage, next to the gauge.
For instance, I'm now at 11% but the icon shows something that would be above 50%.
Only when I'm below 10% it shows a low red gauge.

Is there a fix or will I just remove it and live with the % ?

Comment: This *must* be a bug. I have noticed the same thing in Arch Linux using Gnome 3.20.

Comment: Another related report, including screenshot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/790289/battery-icon-is-fuzzy-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-64-bit-gnome